# Unable to create maven webapp project in sts

Tags: maven

When I create a maven webapp project in sts then I face below problem:

```
could not resolve archetype
archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 
from any of the configured repositories
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding the maven archetype catalog to eclipse. Steps are provided below:

Open Window > Preferences
Open Maven > Archetypes
Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description: maven catalog